# How do I connect live to SQL Server Analysis Services from Power BI Desktop?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, microsoft-live-connect

I am using Power BI Desktop and try to create a live connection (no standard import) to an Analysis Services tabular model in Visual Studio 2017.

In Power BI Desktop, I press Get Data -> Analysis Services.

[image]

I use Power BI Desktop with the same credentials as in the Analysis Services model in Visual Studio.

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this check list:

1. Try to access your cube with SQL Server Management Studio
2. if not ok -> there is a problem with credential or server. If your computer and the server are not in the same domain it could be an issue
3. from power bi desktop try import data rather than live connection
4. can you connect to your model with data tools for visual studio?

The point here is to exclude some configuration to focus on the real problem.

let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today in my work and I make the following and it's working for me

1. process the whole analysis service project from visual studio, not just the cube or one dimensional
2. type the name of the database in the Database(optional) and click ok.
   tell me if this not working with you
   good luck